# Need help with determining open sets

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces

I am currently learning about open and closed sets in metric spaces. I would say that I understand the lecture notes but I can't really apply them. For example the set:
 $${ ((x,f(x)) \in \mathbb{R}^n;x \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1}) f: \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}}\quad is \quad continuos$$
This is apparently a closed set. But wouldn't continuous mean that both f(x) and x are open since inverse Images of open sets are open? I know that that is wrong but why? I assume it comes down to every convergent sequence in ${ \mathbb{R}^n }$ converging to a real value but I don't get how.

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you seem to be confusing sets and functions. In this case, I believe you have a continuous function $f\colon \Bbb R^{n-1}\to\Bbb R$, and from that function you are defining a subset $S$ of $\Bbb R^n = \Bbb R^{n-1}\times\Bbb R$ by $S = \big\{ (x,f(x))\colon x\in\Bbb R^{n-1}\big\}$. (Note that when $n=1$, the set $S$ is the usual graph of $y=f(x)$ in $\Bbb R^2$.) This is in fact a closed set, and proving it is a good exercise.

However, it doesn't make sense to ask whether "$f(x)$ is open or not", or whether "$x$ is open or not", because $f(x)$ and $x$ are not sets. I suspect that getting these definitions very firmly in mind (and closely examining claims or questions that arise as you go, that might seem intuitive but turn out not to be well defined) is really the biggest obstacle at this point.